# Internet Explorer 11: Dragging a link to the new tab button no longer works

Tags: windows, tabs, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-11

[image: http://i.imgur.com/T9Hiaf3.gif]

The image pretty much sums up my problem. It used to work, now it doesn't. What changed?

Comment: That is odd.  It seems to work in IE11 on my system.

Comment: @zoredache Oh, right. I guess it's 11 now. I have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is a feature added in a patch that comes with Windows 8.1, apparently. If you disable "Protected Mode" in the options, this behavior will come back.

- Uncheck the following

Gear -> Internet Options -> Security -> Enable Protected Mode checkbox

Comment: Worked great.  Had to first close all IE windows, then it worked when re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1. Are you using Windows 8? Are you running the IE Modern app or the Desktop version? If so, try using the other IE version.
2. You can also right click the link and choose "Open in new tab".
3. You can also click the link with your middle mouse button (if you
   have one) which, by default, will open the link in a new tab.
4. I just checked my IE 11 and your dragging method works for me. But I
   am running Windows 7 (not sure if you are or not)

   So maybe try:

   - Open "Internet Options"
   - Click the "Advanced" tab
   - Click "Restore Advanced Settings"

Comment: You can see the desktop in the background of his image, so he isn't running the metro IE.

Comment: @Zoredache There are ways to run Modern Apps in desktop mode, but it does appear to be the desktop version of IE. However, it's best if the OP specifies (what OS? IE version?, etc) and we don't make assumptions. Anyway, I'm just offering up multiple suggestions, trying to help.

Answer (score -2):

This is a problem of 64 bit version windows.
If you use 32 bit windows 8.1, dragging a link works fine.